# Understanding Zhang's result of bounded prime gaps

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Here is a link on the internet:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/su3uak2a057yrqv/YitangZhang.pdf

Can someone teach me how to use trivial estimation to reach (6.1) on page 24?
Namely, how to impose $(d,P_0)<D_1$ and replace $\theta$ by $\Lambda$ with acceptable O-term?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This link is mine, I am surprised so many people use it nowadays...

Answer (score 4):

I have asked this question in Mathoverflow and get an answer:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131825/a-technical-question-related-to-zhangs-result-of-bounded-prime-gaps